# FFmpeg adds faint background to PNG watermark

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have an FFmpeg command that I've been using in a few scripts for a while, but have recently noticed that it's adding a slight, mostly transparent background to the PNG watermark that I'm overlaying on top of the video.

What could this problem be caused by, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Without the command, the inputs and an image of the output, no ffmpeg experts will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave it to the FFmpeg experts to answer the first part of the question - what was causing the issue - but after several days of debugging and testing, I managed to solve it by:

- Adding a `format=yuv420p` *filter* to the video stream I was *overlaying the PNG image onto*
- Adding a `format=auto` *option* to the stream that was doing *the PNG overlay itself*

Here's a simplified version of what my command now looks like:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.webm" -loop 1 -i "watermark.png" \
-movflags +faststart \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]format=yuv420p[v0];
 [1:v]lut=a=val*0.7,fade=in:st=10:d=3:alpha=1,fade=out:st=3820:d=3:alpha=1[v1];
 [v1][0:v]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h=ih*0.07[wm_scaled][video];
 [video][wm_scaled]overlay=100:H-h-80:shortest=1:format=auto[outv]" \
-map "[outv]" -map "0:a" -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -c:a libopus "test.mp4"
```